# why a high voted question deleted

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

While reviewing, I came across a question about [**Best book / resources for start learning iOS programming? [closed]**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403049/best-book-resources-for-start-learning-ios-programming) and [**How-to articles for iPhone development and Objective-C**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939/how-to-articles-for-iphone-development-and-objective-c). I agree to the reason for closed, whereas I can't agree with deletion.

This question is marked with 120 votes and favored by 170 people and the other has 409 votes with 600+ users favored.  Better to lock this question instead of deleting.  Is there any reason to delete?

whereas similar other questions are still locked [List of freely available programming books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books), [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Because popularity != suitability for the site.

Comment: To be honest, 120 votes isn't really a lot at all for a question of that age.

Comment: A *Historical Lock* would actually be better IMO.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: But 100k views is.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I agree with you, but see this a very basic which has a chance to re-questioned.  Also this is very good resource too.

Comment: @juergen The value of a book list *that isn't getting updated* is very questionable, though. There's a good argument that it's better to remove it from the Google index altogether

Comment: @juergend Ahh yes, that is a good point. I'm not against historical locks for questions like that, but personally, I don't tend to be a good judge on what to do with such questions. I've made a number of mis-steps on those (from the POV of the community, other mods, and the staff), that I've decided just to stay out of that sort of thing. hehe

Comment: i believe deleting the question would make another noob re-question.Better to close it with proper reasoning as to why it was closed

Comment: @user1671639 As you will see the list of freely available programming books is now hosted on Github. Why not take the content you link to there as well?

Comment: @Nezam One problem with *just* closing is that some will reopen it, as there is a dedicated subset of users who believe those questions are fully 'valid' - even for today. This is one reason 'locking' is often suggested for them.

Comment: I *told you* we need to delete those questions.